# Centering elements on a div

Tags: html, css

This is my setting

```
- 18 square tiles in a div
- The side of the square is about 150px
- There are images inside each square
- Same padding and margin between squares
```

What I want is to, always, have the same amount of space on the left and right of the screen, adjusted to the screen size.

Right now the tiles inside the div are floated left and therefore, the padding on the right side of the div changes, while the left stays the same (I have it set at about 50px). Not really sure if Im explaining my situation well, and Im not sure if this is even possible.

Comment: Please share you existing HTML and CSS, and make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of your issue.

Comment: Did you try nesting the tile divs under a parent div with it's width set to 100%, and setting CSS property text-align: center on the parent level?

Comment: I had tried using text-align center, but the trick was to use display: inline-block. I must confess, I even tried a table, ahhh! Thanks for the help, I learned something new!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to float your elements to get them side-by-side. Simply use `display: inline-block`.

**Example:** [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ESvu/)

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    background: orangered;
}

.tile {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    margin: 5px;
    background: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So I'm assuming your tiles are irregularly sized.
You can use `display: inline-block` instead of `float:left`.

http://jsfiddle.net/5gp75/

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="horizontal tiles">
        <li style="width:100px">Tile 1</li>
        <li style="width:200px">Tile 2</li>
        <li style="width:150px">Tile 3</li>
        <li style="width:70px">Tile 4</li>
        <li style="width:100px">Tile 5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    text-align: center;
}

.horizontal {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.horizontal>li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.tiles>li {
    padding: 1em;
}
```